# OutOfMemoryException - GC verbose confirmed a memory leak, what now?

Tags: memory-leaks, garbage-collection, jvm, out-of-memory, aix

I'm monitoring an app whose GC verbose log looks like this:

[image: GC versose - Used Tenured (after)]

The graph draws the amount of Used Tenured after the GC runs.

As you can see, there's an obvious memory leak, but I was wondering what would be the best next step to find out which component is holding around 50MB of memory each time the GC runs.

The machine is an AIX 6.1 running an IBM's JVM 5.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The pattern in the chart definitely looks like a typical memory leak, building up in tenured space over time. Your best shot would be heap dump analyzers - take a heap dump for example similar to following

```
jmap -dump:format=b,file=dump.bin <your java process id>
```

and analyze the dump file for example with [Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/).